# Add delay to the ffmpeg output (rtmp->rtmp)

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, video-streaming, streaming, delay

I need to add a delay to the output stream. I tried to do this with `tpad`, `-ss`, `-itsoffset`, but didn't work.

`tpad` has shown blank frame for random seconds (I don't know why) and then started streaming. (latest part of the stream, and ignore delay).

I want to push a stream to the output rtmp with 10 seconds delay.

```sh
ffmpeg -i rtmp://input ... -f flv rtmp://output
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Here's [a ffmpeg patch](https://patchwork.ffmpeg.org/project/ffmpeg/patch/20200507202124.10746-1-cus@passwd.hu/#54304), you can read for more information.
2. I test the command 'ffmpeg -i input_rtmp_addr -map 0:v -map 0:a -c copy  -f fifo
   -timeshift 20 -queue_size 6000000 -fifo_format flv output_rtmp_addr' is ok.
3. But there are some limits, you can read the [ffmpeg fifo format](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#fifo-1) and the source code of fifo.c for the detail msg.
4. [![the delay trial][1]][1]
   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZhfQ.png